# How to show selected options and show validation errors when form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, codeigniter, submit, selected

:)
I'm using CodeIgniter. I have radio 3 buttons - when you choose one of them, different dropdowns are shown. First, these dropdowns are hidden, when choose radio button, they show one after another. I want when user click submit button and there are validation errors, these errors to be shown and dropdowns to be shown with selected values. I tried with following code, now dropdowns are not hidden and selected values are shown, but there are no validation errors, because I used `e.preventDefault();`. Please, tell me how could I do that? Thank you in advance! :)
My view is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(":radio").click(function(){
          $('#region').val('Choose region');
          $('#school').val('Chose region');
          $('#teacher').val('Choose school');
          $('#class').val('Choose class');
          $('#class_divisions').val('Choose class division');
      });
  });
 
         

 $(document).ready(function(){


    $('#reg').click(function(e) {
        if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===true){
            $(" .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").show();
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked===true){
            $(" .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school,  .class, .teacher_class").show();
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("radio5").checked===true){
            $(".all_teachers_show").show();
        }
       e.preventDefault();

});
});​
```

My whole view is:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(":radio").click(function(){
          $('#region').val('Choose region');
          $('#school').val('Choose region');
          $('#teacher').val('Choose school');
          $('#class').val('Choose class');
          $('#class_divisions').val('Choose class division');
      });
  });
 
         

 $(document).ready(function(){


    $('#reg').click(function(e) {
        if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===true){
            $(" .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").show();
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked===true){
            $(" .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school,  .class, .teacher_class").show();
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("radio5").checked===true){
            $(".all_teachers_show").show();
        }
       e.preventDefault();

});
});



    function showHide(self, show){

          $(".all_teachers_show, .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
 
          if (show)
              $('.toggle').show();
          else
              $('.toggle').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(self).prop('checked',true);
      }
      
      function show(yes, no){
          if (no)
              $('.school').show();
          else
              $('.school').hide();
          $("region").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
      
      function school_show(yes, no){
  
        if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===true){
           document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class:*';
          if (no)
                $('.teacher').show();
            else
                $('.teacher').hide();
            $("school").prop('checked',false);
            $(yes).prop('checked',true);
        }
       
        if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked===true){
            document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class teacher:*';
          if (no)
              $('.class').show();
          else
              $('.class').hide();
          $("school").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);

        }
      }
     
      function class_show(yes, no){
      
        if (no)
              $('.class').show();
          else
              $('.class').hide();
          $("teacher").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      
      }
      
      function teachers_show(yes, no){
        $(".toggle, .all_teachers_show,  .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
          if (no)
              $('.all_teachers_show').show();
          else
              $('.all_teachers_show').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
       
  </script>   
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#region').change(function() {
                var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                    var $school_sel = $('#school');
                    $school_sel.empty();
                    $school_sel.append("<option>Choose region</option>");
                    var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                        var option = '<option  value="' + val.school_id + '">' + val.school_name + '</option>';
                        $school_sel.append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
  </script>  
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#school').change(function() {
                var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_teachers";
                var postdata = {school: $('#school').val()};
                $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                    var $teacher_sel = $('#teacher');
                    $teacher_sel.empty();
                    $teacher_sel.append("<option>Choose school</option>");
                    var teachers_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $.each(teachers_obj, function(key, val) {
                        var option = '<option value="' + val.user_id + '">' + val.username + '</option>';
                        $teacher_sel.append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });​
```

```html
<?php
  
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open('home/register');

  echo "<h3>Регистрация:</h3><br/>";  
  echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td><label>  Username:* </label></td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : '',
    'value' => set_value('username')
  );
  echo form_input($data);
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td><label> Password:* </label></td><td>";
  $data=array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'class' => form_error('password') ? 'error' : ''
  );
  echo form_password($data);​
 echo "<tr><td><label>  Choose role:* </label> </td><td>";

  $data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id',
    'value' => set_value('role_id', '1'),
    'id' => 'radio1',
    'onclick' => 'showHide(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data); ​
$data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id',
    'value' => set_value('role_id', '2'),
    'id' => 'radio2',
    'onclick' => 'showHide(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data);​
 $data=array(
    'name' => 'role_id',
    'value' => set_value('role_id', '5'),
    'id' => 'radio5',
    'onclick' => 'teachers_show(this, true)'
    );
  echo form_radio($data);
 echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;' ><td><label>  Region:*  </label></td><td>";
  ?>

  <select name='region'   id='region' onChange='show(this, true)'>
  <option value="<?php echo set_select('region'); ?>" >Choose region</option>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option name='region' value= "<?= $row->region ?>" 
        <?php echo 'region' == $row->region ? 'selected="selected"' : 
    '' ?>><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
  <?php
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr class='school' style='display:none;' ><td><label> School:*  
  </label></td><td>";  
  ?>
<select id="school" name="school[]"  onChange='school_show(this, true)'>
 <option value="<?php echo set_select('school[]'); ?>">Choose region</option>
  </select>
  <?php echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr class='teacher' style='display:none;' onChange='class_show(this, true)'><td><label>  Teacher:* 
  </label> </td><td>";
  
  echo '<select id="teacher"  name="teacher[]">';
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo set_select('teacher'); ?>">Choose school</option>
  </select>  
  </td></tr>
<?php
  echo "<tr class='class'  style='display:none;'><td>  <label  id='class_label'> Class:* </label> </td><td>";

  ?>
   <select name='class[]'  id='class'>
   <option value="<?php echo set_select('class[]'); ?>">Choose class</option>
      <?php foreach ($classes as $row) { ?>
        <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->class_id ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
 
   <select name='class_divisions[]'  id='class_divisions'>
    <option value="<?php echo set_select('class_divisions[]'); ?>">Choose division</option>
    <?php foreach ($class_divisions as $row) { ?>
 <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->division ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select>   
  </td></tr>
```

My Controller is:

```html
    public function register()
    {
        
        if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 1 OR $this->input->post('role_id') == 2){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'trim|required'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('school[]', 'School', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'Class', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id[]', 'Role', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('class_divisions[]', 'Class division', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required');
        
        }
        if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 1){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('teacher[]', 'Teacher', 'required');
       
        
        }
         else if ($this->input->post('role_id') == 5 ){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('all_teachers_show', 'All teachers', 'required');

        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->signup();
        }
        else 
        {  
            if( $this->user_model->register())
            {
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'success_reg'; 
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->model('user_model');   
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'register_form'; 
                $data['regions'] = $this->user_model->regions_show();
                $data['classes'] = $this->user_model->classes_show();
                $data['school_show'] = $this->user_model->school_show();
                $data['class_divisions'] = $this->user_model->class_divisions_show();
                $data['all_teachers_show'] = $this->user_model->all_teachers_show();
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }   
        }
    }
public function signup()
    {
        $data['menu']=$this->menu_model->get_menu();
        $data['dynamic_view'] = 'register_form';

        $data['classes'] = $this->user_model->classes_show();
        $data['class_divisions'] = $this->user_model->class_divisions_show();
        $data['all_teachers_show'] = $this->user_model->all_teachers_show();
        $data['school_show'] = $this->user_model->school_show();
        $data['regions'] = $this->user_model->regions_show();
        $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);  
    }
​
```